# center background vertically

Tags: alignment, center

hello I am trying to keep the centre of a background image in the center of the screen
even when the browser is resized very small.I can do this horizontally but not vertically. 
I have created a fiddle link to demonstrate (If you resize your browser 
you can see the background image centering horizontally. [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cCH2Z/116/)

here is the css code I have so far:

```
 #container {

height:450px; background-image:url('http://oi58.tinypic.com/5an82h.jpg');
margin: 0 auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-color: #9FBBE2; }
```

is there anything I can do to keep the background image centred vertically?
I hope to place another div or table over the top of this bkgrnd image.

thanks for help : )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `#container`, it's fixed height and no margin from top, even bg is centered properly, it will still be top relative to window.

Check this updated fiddle, maybe can help you to understand better
http://jsfiddle.net/cCH2Z/117/

But honestly, I don't think your solution is the best choice for these following reasons:

1. If this background is the whole bg for entire app, why place it in a `#container`? Why not place it directly into `body` or `html` element?
2. If #1 is not true, you still have better way to control it precisely. Divided your `#container` for 2/more parts horizontally, use margin to control the relationship of position of your header.

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <div id="container">

      <div id="top">
        <!-- Here goes your content need to over the top of bg -->
      </div>

      <!-- Adjust distance between #top and #center -->

      <div id="center">
        <!-- Here goes your bg and other stuff -->
      </div>

      ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nightire you are awesome!! : P  thank you.! I shall try your other idea too. Yes it is a background for an entire web page, I hope to have a table or a div centred in the middle going down the page which will include pictures and text and maybe a tab panel up the top. I  am trying hard to learn, so your help is amazing. thank you once again!!! : )